# Using pimpl with Templated Class and explicitly instantiated templates

Tags: c++, templates, explicit, pimpl-idiom

How do I use pimpl for a templated class, when I explicitly instantiate the templates?

All I need is an example code.

What I have tried is:

```
// MyTemplatedClass.h

template< class T >
class MyTemplatedClass
{
private:
    class Impl;
    Impl* _pimpl;

public:
    void PublicMethod();
}
```

Here my implementation goes:

```
// MyTemplatedClass.cpp

template< class T >
class MyTemplatedClass<T>::Impl
{
    public:
        void PublicMethod();
}

template <class T>
void MyTemplatedClass<T>::Impl::PublicMethod()
{
    ...
}
```

Forwarding method call to implementation class:

```
template< class T >
void MyTemplatedClass<T>::PublicMethod()
{
    _pimpl->PublicMethod();
}
```

Explicit instantiation:
Example with int and double:

```
template class MyTemplatedClass< int >;
template class MyTemplatedClass< double >;
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: When something "doesn't [seem to] work," *always* tell us exactly *how* it "doesn't [seem to] work." In other words, what errors are you getting?

Comment: When I try to forward the PublicMethod, the compiler doesn't detect my PublicMethod.
_pimpl-> should give me a list of available methods, but no one exists.

Comment: You're talking about your IDE, right? The code analysis in your IDE and your compiler are generally two different things; if your IDE just does not show you that a method is available, that does not necessarily mean that the compiler wouldn't find it if you use it there.

Comment: It gives me the error:
C2227: left of '->PublicMethod' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
1>          MyTemplatedClass.cpp(65) : while compiling class template member function 'void MyTemplatedClass<T>::PublicMethod()'

Comment: @user1507569 Seems as if the compiler can't find the proper definition of `_pimpl`. Try prefixing it with `this->`.

Comment: It gives me about the same error.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you add the ';' at the end of the class definitions? Otherwise, what compiler are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This would answer your question, but I doubt it does what you hoped to achieve. I suspect you would want to declare the template implementation outside the scope of MyTemplatedClass. It might be a better design to inherit from the template implementation instead of having it as a member variable.

If you compiler does not support extern template declarations I cannot see that having a template pointer to implementation adds any value. You would after all have to have the implementation details you wanted to hide away in the header file anyway.

```
#include <iostream>

template < class T > class MyTemplatedClass {
private:
  template < class U> class Impl {
  public:
     void ImplPublicMethod() {
           std::cout << "Standard implementation" << std::endl;
           }
  };

  Impl<T> * _pimpl;
public:
  MyTemplatedClass() : _pimpl(new Impl<T>) { }
  ~MyTemplatedClass() { delete _pimpl; }
  void publicMethod() {
     _pimpl->ImplPublicMethod();
  }
};

template<> class MyTemplatedClass<int> {
private:
  class Impl {
  public:
     void ImplPublicMethod() {
          std::cout << "Integer specialisation" << std::endl;
     };
 };

 Impl * _pimpl;
public:
  MyTemplatedClass() : _pimpl(new Impl) { }
  ~MyTemplatedClass() { delete _pimpl; }
  void publicMethod() {
     _pimpl->ImplPublicMethod();
  }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

   MyTemplatedClass<char> charVersion;
   charVersion.publicMethod();

   MyTemplatedClass<int> intVersion;
   intVersion.publicMethod();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I must have had a brain haemorrhage. A little typo made the compiler angry. The code I wrote in the question works fine.

Answer (score -1):

Methods of a template class always have to be defined in the header. You cannot have a `MyTemplatedClass.cpp` as compilation unit on its own. What you can do is to `#include` the file containing the definitions of the methods at the end of `MyTemplatedClass.h` so that declaration and definition are at least separated at file level. So your problem may be fixed by adding

```
#include "MyTemplatedClass.cpp"
```

at the end of `MyTemplatedClass.h`.

I use pimpls with template classes in my own code, it works for me that way. Your code looks about right - I'd use a `std::unique_ptr` for pimpl, but I don't see any problems with how you're doing it.

Comment: -1: Member functions of template classes always have to be defined in the header *unless they are explicitly instantiated somewhere in the program.* The OP is doing the explicit instantiation, so this doesn't apply here.