# PIMPL idiom for a pointer to a class in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, pimpl-idiom

I have a working interface for two programs (`ProgramA` and `ProgramB`) that I would like to improve decoupling both programs as much as possible. The case that I want to cover is making a call from `ProgramA` to a class from `ProgramB` (`Compute_Prop`) that can only be initialized with some arguments which I do not now in advance. Hence, I use a pointer in the header. Currently, I have something like this:

**interface.h**

```
#include "programB.h" // loads Compute_Prop

class Compute {
  public:
    Compute();
    Compute(targ1 arg1, targ2 arg2);
    ~Compute();
    // some methods ...
  private:
    Compute_Prop* compute;
};
```

**interface.cpp**

```
#include "programB.h"
#include "interface.h"

#include "programA.h"

Compute::Compute() = default;

Compute::~Compute() {                                                                                                     
    delete compute;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
}

Compute::Compute(arg1, arg2) {

  // do something ... to get data

  compute = new Compute_Prop( &data, arg2 );
}
```

Then, I try to imitate the PIMPL idiom with the following

**interface.h**

```
#include "programB.h" // loads Compute_Prop

class Compute {
  public:
    Compute();
    Compute(targ1 arg1, targ2 arg2);
    ~Compute();
    // some methods ...
  private:
    class PIMPL;
    PIMPL* compute;
};
```

**interface.cpp**

```
#include "programB.h"
#include "interface.h"

#include "programA.h"

Compute::PIMPL = Compute_Prop;

Compute::Compute() = default;

Compute::~Compute() {                                                                             
    delete compute;                                                                                                                                                                     
}

Compute::Compute(arg1, arg2) {

  // do something ... to get data

  compute = new Compute_Prop( &data, arg2 );
}
```

but the compiler says:

```
error: expected unqualified-id
  Compute::PIMPL = Compute_Prop;
                 ^
```

I guess that it has something to do with Compute_Prop not having
an empty constructor. I can't come up with something that works. What should I do? Something like a pointer to a pointer, maybe? As a restriction, I cannot modify `programB`.

Note: As it is probably already clear from above, my understanding of low level C++/C is scarce.

EDIT: I introduced the corrections suggested by @n.m. and @Matthieu Brucher

Comment: Your member declaration syntax is wrong throughout. You are not supposed to repeat the class name *inside the class*. So no `Compute::Compute()`, just `Compute()`. I have no idea why some compilers accept the syntax you are using, it's totally illegal.

Comment: You cannot assign types in C++. Once you declare `class PIMPL;` it expects that there will be a class named `PIMPL`. Pointer declared as `PIMPL* ptr;` will always have the type `PIMPL` of that promised class. `Compute::PIMPL = Compute_Prop;` is not possible, because `PIMPL` and `Compute_Prop` are both immutable types. It won't convert all `PIMPL`s into `Compute_Prop`s.

Comment: if ( compute != nullptr ) {                                                                                                               
    delete compute;                                                                                                                                                   
    compute = nullptr;                                                                                                                                                                                     
  } No!! just delete it, or even better, use std::unique_ptr!!

Comment: `Compute::PIMPL` is a type, you cannot have this `type = value` syntax. You need a name. Something like `Compute::compute` perhaps. `Compute::PIMPL Compute::compute = ...`.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Even if compute is defined sometimes? I mean, when only Compute() is called. The real program is more complicated, when I tried with ``unique_ptr`` it failed so I decided to keep it working.

Comment: yes, delete already does the check, it's a useless redundancy. And if you have problems with using unique_ptr, then it means that you have other things to fix as well, ceuase that's how the pimlp should be handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation should use an interface (or in fact a class with only abstract methods) as a base class.
You cannot assign types in C++. You can only create typedefs and aliases, like that:

```
using PIMPLType = Compute_Prop;
```

However this won't work in your case.
This is how it should be implemented (also with possibility of multiple implementations):

```
class IImplementation
{
public:
    virtual void saySomething() = 0;
};

class ImplementationA : public IImplementation
{
public:
    virtual void saySomething() override {
        std::cout << "A";
    }
};
class ImplementationB : public IImplementation
{
public:
    virtual void saySomething() override {
        std::cout << "B";
    }
};

class Foo {
    IImplementation *pimpl;
public:
    Foo()
        : pimpl(new ImplementationA)
    {}

    ~Foo() { delete pimpl; }

    void saySomething() {
         pimpl->saySomething();
    }
};
```

Comment: I will investigate how to materialize it. Also, a point of concern is speed, methods of ``Compute`` are called millions of times and can take either milliseconds or minutes, hours.

Answer (score 0):

I may have come across a simple solution. I post it here so you can judge if it is adequate, or even if it can be improved --- sure. I am convinced that runtime polymorphism is not needed, not even polymorphism. The member variable `compute` is going to be a pointer to a `Compute_Prop` type anyway. Then, given that performance is critical here: why running the extra overhead of virtual member functions?

The point here is to reach an implementation that hides the inclusion of `Compute_Prop` without loosing performance. How? This particular solution uses a templated class and then explicit instantiation. The point is that instantiation can be done in the implementation. Got it from [a Fluent C++ blog post](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/04/28/extract-interface-cpp/). Also, [this post](https://anteru.net/blog/2008/11/19/318/index.html) has hints for  how the implementation should be done. A prototype would be:

**interface.h**

```
template <typename T>
class Compute {
  public:
    Compute();
    Compute(targ1 arg1, targ2 arg2);
    ~Compute();
    // some methods ...
  private:
    T* compute; // No need to state that is going to be T:=Compute_Prop
};
```

**interface_impl.h**

```
#include "interface.h"    
#include "programA.h"

template <typename T>
Compute::Compute() = default;

template <typename T>
Compute::~Compute() {                                                                                                              
    delete compute;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
}

template <typename T>
Compute::Compute(arg1, arg2) {

  // do something ... to get data

  compute = new T( &data, arg2 );
}
```

**interface.cpp**

```
 #include "interface.h"
 #include "interface_impl.h"
 #include "programA.h"
 #include "programB.h" // loads Compute_Prop

 int main(int argc, char** argv) {

   template class Compute<Compute_Prop>;

 }
```

Another related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203693/using-pimpl-with-templated-class-and-explicitly-instantiated-templates) that might be useful for those with the same dilemma.